# Why would aliens fill a quarantine space with inert gas?

Tags: atmosphere, military-defense, megastructures

While experimenting on a Mysterious Alien Artefact at a Super Secret Research Facility, the protagonists accidentally activate what turns out to be a homing beacon, and teleport everything in a sphere a couple of kilometers in diameter to the inside of the alien race's 'arrivals hall', a gas-giant-sized megastructure.

I'd like to explore the consequences of taking a chunk of planet away from the rest of the planet, particularly the sudden loss of gravity, rapidly cooling temperature and improvisation of breathable air, but the sad reality is that the most realistic sequence of events is 1) all the buildings that weren't designed for a sudden loss of external atmospheric pressure explode, then 2) everybody dies within minutes.  Even the sort of biohazard containment labs and secure vaults you might expect in a SSRF are unlikely to be designed for this sort of eventuality.

Fortunately, the guiding hand of Plot has decided that the aliens decided to fill the interior of their arrivals hall with an inert gas like argon, to a low-but-human-survivable pressure (maybe 20kPa).  This means the humans can restrict themselves to worrying about finding oxygen supplies and dealing with the cold, rather than immediately exploding.

My question is: **why would the aliens do this?**  A gas-giant-sized cloud of gas is, to put it mildly, an HVAC nightmare; it's not a plausible origin environment for them to be trying to replicate; as an inert gas it can't be part of their metabolism.  The only possibility I can think of is that it's a defence mechanism to diminish the efficacy of laser or electrostatic weapons, in what is perhaps a 'quarantine zone' where unidentified travellers are triaged to see if they're a threat.  Why else might they have done this?

Comment: Hmmm. Buildings explode at 1 atm pressure differential but are just fine at 0.8 atm pressure differential? That's one fine line to thread.

Comment: Not so much that they explode, as they vent (with various broken windows and doors), and then the humans inside them die of vacuum exposure.  Most terrestrial buildings couldn't be jury-rigged to maintain enough of a pressure differential to keep humans inside them alive.  With *some* external atmosphere, they don't _need_ to maintain a pressure differential, just be sealed enough that the breathable air inside doesn't exchange too much with the non-breathable air outside.

Comment: ... Because it's an alien quarantine? Inert gas is unlikely to explode or lead to any other unexpected chemical reactions (such as human life) and vacuum is just annoying.

Comment: Humans *can't* survive with air at 0.2 atm, so this kills them almost as quickly, certainly too quickly for any to figure out they need to find pure oxygen and come up with a way to do so. If the aliens routinely teleport large chunks of planetary surfaces to this location for evaluation of the inhabitants, why would they not provide an enclosure with an atmospheric environment matching that of the origin planet? Why is this not a problem already solved by the aliens?

Comment: They teleport mysterious uncontained biohazards *inside their big structures*?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the [help/on-topic] specifically states, "If ... you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." We do not answer questions about choices, decisions, or motivations. Besides, haven't you answered your own question? They do it to keep the buildings from exploding....

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 reasons, but they are all a little weak.

First, this is their their natural atmosphere. Remember the Earth's atmosphere is [~78% $N_2$](https://www.noaa.gov/jetstream/atmosphere), an extremely nonreactive gas. If you replaced the with more reactive gasses like $O_2$ or $CO_2$, you would pretty quickly kill people. To an alien, filling a space with ~80% argon or helium could be a non-decision because that's what they normally breath.

Second, the inert gas ensures no reactions occur with the object being studied. To be honest, the Super Secret Research Facility in [I Love Bees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Love_Bees) does exactly this. They store alien artifacts in a chamber completely filled with a noble gas in order to preserve it. It can be difficult to store something large under pure vacuum, so filling the space with something the subject probably won't react with is the best you can do.

Third, they are trying to kill any biohazards that come through the teleporter. They reason that whatever gets teleported in, it will have a metabolism that will require some gasses. Since inert gasses cannot be part of that metabolism, filling the space with inert gasses is a way to ensure the germs are asphyxiated.

The problem with the first option breathing noble gasses will not in itself be harmful to humans. As long as you also get plenty of $O_2$, you will be fine inhaling noble gases. [Helium is actually mixed into many SCUBA tanks](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Inorganic_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/08%3A_Chemistry_of_the_Main_Group_Elements/8.14%3A_The_Noble_Gases/8.14.02%3A_Properties_of_Nobel_Gases) because breathing too much nitrogen while under pressure can cause problems. The problem with options 2 and 3 is that even today storing things under vacuum is not **impossibly** hard, just a pain to do right. If these aliens are so advanced they can teleport kilometers of random space around, why haven't they figured out [Bell Jars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_jar).